# how to write command to save selected text?

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block

I want to save selected text in vim. I use command `:'<,'>w! ~/save.txt`.

How to write a short command instead of it, or mapping it to key mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

`vnoremap <Leader>s :w! ~/save.txt <CR>`

Just paste this into your `init.vim`. This assumes you have the text highlighted and are currently in visual mode. Just hit `Leader`+`s` and it will save the selection for you.